# How js.devexpress.com dxDataGrid export to excel with custom header?

Tags: javascript, excel, datagrid, devexpress, devextreme

I am trying to export [js.devexpress.com dxDataGrid](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/?version=16_1) in excel with custom header but no result. I just want to insert one top row with some details like company name but not found any solution.

Export to excel demo : [js.devexpress.com dxDataGrid Demo](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/data_grid-export-export_to_excel).

Is anyone deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, as of now (2016-10-08) DevExtreme suite doesn't support customized export of dxDataGrid to Excel, neither custom headers nor custom cell formatting are supported.

See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T430687 .

You could insert custom header into exported Excel doc as well as have control over individual cell formatting if you were using their other grid control ASPxGridView, but it requires your app to use ASP.NET.